# How to draw a UILabel with a different blend mode in draw(_ rect: CGRect) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgcontext, blending

So I have a `UILabel` that is being drawn on top of a gradient image (that is a `UIImageView`). It looks sorta like this:

[image]

I'm trying to change the `blendMode` of the graphics context in the `UILabel`'s `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function so that it draws the label but blended with the background with a `softLight` blending mode.

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here is the code I have in the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
     if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        context.setBlendMode(.softLight)
        self.textColor.set()
        self.drawText(in: rect)
   }
 }
```

This code just renders the top picture and not the blended version. This is not all that I've tried, I've tried so much other things but I just don't understand `CGContext`'s and the `draw` function in particular.

Most answers on SO are either in old objective-c and are deprecated/broken or swift and too complicated (use Metal for example). I just want to draw the text in the context I have and set the context's blending mode to soft light. There has to be an easy way!

Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't blend views this way; they have separate layer hierarchies that are resolved independently. Move the gradient and text on `CALayer` objects and blend those (or draw them by hand inside the same view). For example:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,
                                UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        return gradientLayer
    }()

    let textLayer: CATextLayer = {
        let textLayer = CATextLayer()
        let astring = NSAttributedString(string: "Text Example",
                                         attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Wide", size: 60)!])
        textLayer.string = astring
        textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
        textLayer.bounds = astring.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: .max, height: .max),
                                                options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)
        return textLayer
    }()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            gradientLayer.bounds = bounds
            gradientLayer.render(in: context)

            context.saveGState()
            context.setBlendMode(.softLight)

            context.translateBy(x: center.x - textLayer.bounds.width / 2,
                                y: center.y - textLayer.bounds.height / 2)

            textLayer.position = center
            textLayer.render(in: context)
            context.restoreGState()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You seem to be the only one who understood and were able to give me with what I wanted. Unfortunately, my label is moving, and so I want it to update its "blend color" at every time step. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: That's just animation. You'll need some property that indicates the location of the text. Use `animate(withDuration:animations:)` to modify that property, and add a `didSet` for that property to call `setNeedsDisplay` when it's changed. (In principle there are more performant approaches, but they're more complicated, so don't worry about that unless you encounter a serious performance issue. Core Graphics and Core Animation are already very good at optimizing this stuff even when you take the easy route, and most naïve attempts at optimizing just fight the system and make it worse.)

Comment: Note that you can do this all with a `CALayer` rather than a `UIView`, but animating custom properties of a `CALayer` turns out to be slightly trickier than it sounds. It's not hard, but it's subtle enough that I usually don't recommend it to people unless they need it.

Comment: That seems understandable... I was trying to get it to be moved by tapping and dragging around and not using animation... so I'm not sure how that will work. I'm actually thinking of just using Metal to render this out as it seems like the fastest approach (in case a user is very aggressive with their gestures)

Comment: If you know what you're doing (i.e. have a background in OpenGL), then Metal can be very fast. If you don't know what you're doing, then Metal can easily be slower than doing it naively, because the system is already built on Metal (or OpenGL) by people who do know what they're doing. It's very easy to use Metal incorrectly. The whole point of it is managing pipelines. Doing this with dragging is the same as animation, just set the property in the gesture recognizer rather than in `animate(withDuration:animation:)`.

Comment: If you're looking for short-term consulting work to tackle this problem, this is the kind of project I often work on. I'm completely booked right now, but if you are looking for help in December, let me know and I may be able to assist further. Best of luck. robnapier@gmail.com

Comment: Hmmm, that's very interesting! I actually teach an intro course in OpenGL, and have worked a lot with CUDA and a little bit in Vulkan. I'm super busy right now as well so if I were to do it in Metal, I'd have to learn all the pipeline stuff and how to pass in the background as textures and all that jazz. Do you mind if I email you questions once I have things up and running in December?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees I can thoroughly recommend Rob, having attended a couple of his workshops and presentations. Right now, in my Xcode "most recents" file menu I literally have a file called called "FunctionalSwiftRobNapier.playground" from one of his workshops.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees I'd be happy to look at it, but if you're already experienced in OpenGL, you may want someone more advanced in that world (I'm good at taking the uninitiated up a level, but if you're intermediate, you want an expert). Janie Clayton is who I turn to when I want to understand Metal. http://redqueencoder.com I do a lot of performance work across a variety of topics on iOS, but Metal isn't my expertise. (Personally, I'd probably keep this in Core Graphics, moving to Core Image if necessary, but I wouldn't crack open Metal for it. Not that Metal is wrong, just my toolkit.)

Comment: Which would you say is best for performance/battery life? I also wanted to add some motion blur to the movement. Previously, my thought was to use a third party library, but thinking about it again, if I'm going to use Metal then I might as well add Motion Blur as part of my Metal code since that will be a lot faster. But I don't want my app's menu bar to be a huge drain on battery.

Comment: The answer is "work in the highest-layer you can, profile, and refine." Metal isn't magic "go faster" dust. If you're going to work in Metal, then yes, you absolutely must do all the work in Metal. Moving back and forth will destroy performance. But personally I'd work in CoreImage, and see what the issues are (if any). Metal generally means either "I have a problem that other frameworks don't address" or "I think I'm smarter than Apple about this." The former happens, the latter…happens, but is rarer. Assume if there were a straight-forward Metal solution, UIKit would be using it.

Answer (score -1):

So in case your text is really a label you could try it with changing the opacity like for normal labels. I assume you're familiar with setting an alpha to a label. Please find below one example for setting an alpha for a label:

```
label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.25)
```

Please give me a hint, if it's not a label - then it should be more complicated.

Comment: It is a label, but I don't want to change the opacity, I want to specifically change the blending mode to soft light (or other modes).

Comment: @AlexWoe89 I need exact blending too - `UILabel` has gray color, background view has green color and their intersection should be white text color. You will never achieve this with opacity params only