# Blend Uiimage with moving & pan geture

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to Blend two image on which I can move or scale or rotate with foreground image wile bled-Modes is applied. I know how to blend image but I cannot move or scale and bled two images simultaneously.

Example: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IFTagT3p0Xx0l7Qn3n675zpsTGbTrDdD

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865660/how-to-draw-a-uilabel-with-a-different-blend-mode-in-draw-rect-cgrect-in-swi/46876386#46876386

Comment: no, it's not I want use blend mode with move and scale zoom with UIImage not UIlable

Comment: That doesn't change anything. That just means you need to draw an image, rather than a string; it's the same process.

Comment: on that code i can blend uiimage but i can't pan,pinch or zoom uiimage same as i show in my video.

Comment: Yes; you'd have to implement gesture recognizers to adjust it. There is no quick answer that I'm aware of this problem. You'll need to write code to implement it. The point is that you need to draw what you want on layers and then blend them within one view. If the question is looking for a fully worked out solution, that's too broad for SO. Draw them on layers; add gesture recognizers to drag them around.